# How can I disable sound effect of deleting files in Elementary OS 5?

Tags: pantheon-files, release-juno, sound

This question has been asked before but the answer is not working in 5.0. There is no sound effects options anywhere.
How Can I disable the file delete sound effects in 5.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Event Sounds option in the Sound settings to disable this sound.

In previous versions of Elementary OS this option didn't work. The old workaround is below.

I think the "Event Sounds" option in the Sound settings is supposed to disable this sound but it doesn't seem to work. I've opened an issue here: https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/766

As an ugly work around, you could delete or change the name of the file that creates that sound.

For example to stop the trash sound from playing:

1. Open Terminal
2. Run **`io.elementary.files-pkexec`**
3. Enter your password
4. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and paste in `/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/`
5. Delete or rename `trash-empty.oga

Comment: "Event Sounds" option works now. So, no need for the workaround.

Comment: @TrigonaMinima thanks for the reminder, I'll update the answer

Answer (score 1):

Please raise an issue at https://github.com/elementary/files/issues.  I agree Files should at least honor the event sounds setting.

Answer (score 1):

As of release, and a few months later, this in fact has not been fixed.  If someone call point me to a place that says otherwise, I would appreciate it, but I am forced to delete both 'freedesktop' and 'elementary' folders in /usr/share/sounds in order to disable sound effects.

And I'm a fairly experienced user, so this is a pretty serious bug for the average user.